# How do I reverse an array in JavaScript in 16 characters or less without .reverse()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

I'm trying to solve a [challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/reverse-it-quickly/train/javascript) on Codewars which requires you to reverse an array in JavaScript, in 16 characters or less. Using `.reverse()` is not an option.

The maximum number of characters allowed in your code is 28, which includes the function name `weirdReverse`, so that leaves you with just 16 characters to solve it in. The constraint -

> Your code needs to be as short as possible, in fact not longer than 28 characters

Sample input and output -

> Input: an array containing data of any types. Ex: `[1,2,3,'a','b','c',[]]`
>
> Output: `[[],'c','b','a',3,2,1]`

The starter code given is -

```
weirdReverse=a=>
```

My solution (**29** characters) is -

```
weirdReverse=a=>a.sort(()=>1)
```

which of course fails -

> Code length should less or equal to 28 characters.
>
> your code length = 29 - Expected: 'code length <= 28', instead got: 'code length > 28'

I'm not sure what else to truncate here.

Note - I did think about posting this question on [CodeGolf SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com), but I felt it wouldn't be a good fit there, due to the limited scope.

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can do it by using for loop  

like for (var i= array.length-1; i >=0; i--{
  /// do your staff here 
}

Comment: To the people above, please read the question fully. I feel like if this question was restructured/reworded it would fit nicely with codeGolf rather than on SO, but I don't know their policy on using them to answer challenges on another site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: Cheers for the site btw, signed up. Looks fun!

Comment: `f=a=>a.length?[a.pop(),...f(a)]:[]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd like to give you a hint, without giving you the answer:

You're close, but you can save characters by *not* using something you need to add in your code.

By adding the thing you *won't* use, you can remove `()`.

---

Spoiler (answer):

```js
// Note: this only really works for this specific case.
// Never EVER use this in a real-life scenario.

var a = [1,2,3,'a','b','c',[]]

weirdReverse=a=>a.sort(x=>1)
//                     ^ That's 1 character shorter than ()

console.log(weirdReverse(a))
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Except that this [absolutely won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24080785/1048572)? Try with an array longer than 10, which will use a different sorting algorithm...

Comment: @Bergi: Code golf exercises like there are more about _"What works for this specific case"_ (which it does)

Comment: @Cerbrus Meh, I could solve specific cases by just returning a constant. The test suite provided by the challenge author looks much like he was asking for a generic solution. There is no mention of "needs to work only on arrays shorter than 10 items, only with V8".

Comment: @Bergi: Try the answer's code in the codewars challenge. It's accepted. Apparently, it's generig enough. I don't know of a different (just as short) method to reverse an array. Now, what point are you trying to make here? That this isn't code you'd put in production?

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, exactly that. I fear that not even the original author was aware of this limitation, and instead thinks of it as a clever trick. Before it becomes popular, someone should place a clear disclaimer on it.

Comment: @Bergi: I added a disclaimer in the code. Better? :-)

Comment: @Cerbrus Thanks!