# How do i reverse an array in javaScript without .reverse()

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I'm trying to reverse the contents of an array. My approach works well when the contents of the said array are of same type. but once they're of different types it just doesn't work.
 Constraint is that i can't use the `.reverse()` method and if possible, without creating a new array.
The answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46092085/17134679) is close to what i want but i don't understand it.

Here is my code...

reverse.js

```
#!/usr/bin/node
exports.rev = function (list) {
  for (let i = 0, j = (list.length - 1); i <= (list.length / 2); i++, j--) {
    [list[i], list[j]] = [list[j], list[i]];
  }
  return (list);
};
```

main.js

```
#!/usr/bin/node
const rev = require('./reverse').rev;

console.log(rev([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(rev(["School", 89, { id: 12 }, "String"]));
```

Expected:
`[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`
`["String", { id: 12 }, 89, "School"]`

What I got:
`[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`
`["String", 89, { id: 12 }, "School"]`

Comment: Probably you're swapping the central elements twice, and swapping them twice is like not swapping them at all. You should fix it replacing `i <= (list.length / 2)`  with `i < (list.length / 2)`, even if I didn't test it yet

Comment: This also explains why reverting an odd number of elements doesn't cause any problem (in your first example you're swapping `3` twice, which is fine)

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina Oh, yeah! This works! I never imagined that will be the source of the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out that your code almost works. You just need to modify the condition a bit to

```
i < (list.length / 2) //not `<=`
```

```js
function rev(list) {
  for (let i = 0, j = (list.length - 1); i < (list.length / 2); i++, j--) {
    [list[i], list[j]] = [list[j], list[i]];
  }
  return (list);
};

console.log(rev([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(rev(["School", 89, { id: 12 }, "String"]));
```

Comment: I just modified my question to not clone a new array

Comment: Not really a requirement though, but what if i wanted this without having to use an extra array.

Comment: Already posted before i saw your comment

Answer (score 0):

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let reverse = [];

for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    reverse.push(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: In this way you're creating a new array, not what OP wants

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a `for` loop like this:

```js
let arr = ["School", 89, { id: 12 }, "String"];

let newArr = [];

for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  newArr.push(arr[i])
}
console.log(newArr);
```

Expected output: `["String", [object Object] { id: 12 }, 89, "School"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can user a recursion to reverse

You can use Spread operator(`...`) along with distructure assignment for that.

```js
function rev(arr) {
  const [first, ...rest] = arr
  return arr.length > 1 ? [...rev(rest), first] : arr
}

console.log(rev([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(rev(["School", 89, { id: 12 }, "String"]));
```

`const [first, ...rest] = arr` is a shortcut for:

```
const first = arr[0]
const rest = arr.slice(1)
```

However, `...rev(rest)` will spread items of returned array and spread them. So, `[...rev(rest), first]` will keep the output of rev first and then push `first` at the end of array.

---

If you are comfortable with mutation of original array, try this

```js
function rev(arr) {
  return arr.length > 1 ? [arr.pop(), ...rev(arr)] : arr
}

console.log(rev([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(rev(["School", 89, { id: 12 }, "String"]));
```

Comment: I'm new to JS so i don't really understand what `...` does but i'm interested in this method.

Comment: Updated my answer with explanation. Let me know if you have more queries regarding it

Answer (score 0):

Already good answers (and examples of arrays) here

My try with native methods:

```js
const rev = (arr) => {
  len = arr.length;
  for (i = 1; i<= len; i++) arr.splice(len-i,0,arr.shift());
}

const array = ["School", 89, { id: 12 }, "String"];

console.log("original",array);
rev(array);
console.log("reversed",array);
```